# ResourceDictionary vs Resources directly under Window.Resources

Tags: wpf, xaml

Please pardon me if this was already asked, I have done a quick search to find out if it was however.

My question is what is the difference between the following two

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
   <local:SomeClass x:Key="myobj" />
 </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

And

```
<Window.Resources>
 <local:SomeClass x:Key="myobj" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're completely equivalent.  The `ResourceDictionary` object is implicitly assumed to be the child in the second example ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) calls it the "XAML implicit collection usage").  I only ever use the longer form when adding `MergedDictionaries`.